# Performance issue due to table scan vs index scan

Tags: performance

A simple SOQL query on contact object is performing full table scan instead of index scan in our Salesforce development org and same query works fine in production org. There are around 6 million records. It used to work fine before, but, somehow, since couple of days we have been noticing significant performance issue due this table scan.

```
select id, email, name, Isdeleted,username__c from contact where email = 'btlorch@testwk.com'
```

[image]

Salesforce Feedback and resolution steps:

It seems to be platform encryption turned on in this sandbox.
Also noticed that you have been using CaseInsensitiveDeterministicEncryption

As per the below doc, Queries against these fields, when encrypted with case-insensitive deterministic encryption, can perform poorly with large tables. For optimal query performance, use custom indexes instead of standard indexes. Contact - Email is one of the fields mentioned in this doc.

> > https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.security_pe_deterministic_considerations.htm&type=5

The unaffected working org it appears they don't use Platform Encryption
that is why it is working more effectively there.

We have created the two-column index in this sandbox and should improve the performance. Please validate and let us know if this is working fine now.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Performance issue was due to turning on platform encryption and using CaseInsenstiveDeterminsticEncryption on standard index column.

We have to contact Salesforce to create a custom two column index when turning on platform encryption on a standard indexed column. After creating custom two column index, the query will perform well by doing index scan instead of a full table scan.

Query plan after the changes:

[image]